# Renaming file in same directory using Python

Tags: python

So I'm trying to iterate through a list of files that are within a subfolder named `eachjpgfile` and change the file from `doc` to the subfolder `eachjpgfile` mantaining the file's name but when I do this it adds the file to directory before `eachjpgfile` rather than keeping it in it.  Looking at the code below, can you see why is it doing this and how can I keep it in the `eachjpgfile` directory?

Here is the code:

```
for eachjpgfile in filelist:
    os.chdir(eachjpgfile)
    newdirectorypath = os.curdir
    list_of_files = os.listdir(newdirectorypath)
    for eachfile in list_of_files:
         onlyfilename = os.path.splitext(eachfile)[0]
         if onlyfilename == 'doc':
            newjpgfilename = eachfile.replace(onlyfilename,eachjpgfile)
            os.rename(eachfile, newjpgfilename)
```

Comment: `os.chdir(eachjpgfile)` What?

Comment: There is quite a lot wrong with this. :)

Comment: This will be much clearer if you use `os.walk` instead of reinventing this particular kind of wheel...

Comment: That was my silly way of changing the current directory to a new directory called eachjpgfile

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there is a better way.  I didn't add my zipfile code here but basically I'm extracting this doc file into a new directory with the same name as zip file and trying to rename this doc file also to that same name but keep it in it's original directory.

Comment: Why not rename on extract then (or rather, extract into the new name)?

Comment: Not sure how I rename during extract.  There are 2 files in each zip file, want to extract both to new folder but I can only rename the one named 'doc'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of weird stuff going on in here, but I think the one that's causing your particular issue is using 'eachjpgfile' in 'eachfile.replace'.
From what I can tell, the 'eachjpgfile' you're passing in is a full-path, so you're replacing 'doc' in the filename with '/full/path/to/eachjpgfile', which puts it parallel to the 'eachjpgfile' directory regardless of your current working directory.

You could add a line to split the path/file names prior to the replace:

```
for eachjpgfile in filelist:
    os.chdir(eachjpgfile)
    newdirectorypath = os.curdir
    list_of_files = os.listdir(newdirectorypath)
    for eachfile in list_of_files:
         onlyfilename = os.path.splitext(eachfile)[0]
         if onlyfilename == 'doc':
            root, pathName= os.path.split(eachjpgfile) #split out dir name
            newjpgfilename = eachfile.replace(onlyfilename,pathName)
            os.rename(eachfile, newjpgfilename)
```

which is a very dirty fix for a very dirty script.  :)

Comment: That worked, thanks.  Yes, it's very dirty but it does work now.  I probably should try to clean it up but very much a beginner and I'm sure it shows.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import os

path = '.'
recursive = False   # do not descent into subdirs

for root,dirs,files in os.walk( path ) :
    for name in files :
        new_name = name.replace( 'aaa', 'bbb' )

        if name != new_name :
            print name, "->", new_name
            os.rename( os.path.join( root, name),
                   os.path.join( root, new_name ) )

    if not recursive :
        break
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  Using the os.walk is I'm sure a much better route here.  I will consider this for cleaning up my code.